# How to search in a Set of vectors of integers

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to form a set of vectors of integers and on checking if the same solution already exists in the set, I am not getting correct answer.

This is in regards to C++11. I had posted a similar kind of query earlier as well but had not got any meaningful replies. 
Why is it that whenever we form a map or set of vectors, is is not able to recognize if I insert a vector which is identical to the one I have already inserted ? 
I have been searching for an answer since months. Also, since this behavior is allowed in other languages like Java, there must be a work around this. It would be great if someone can point out why this behavior isn't working the way I expect it to and what should be the probable solution to this.

The code below is a solution to 3Sum problem on Leetcode, but doesn't work because of exactly what I have explained above.

```
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>>result;
        unordered_map<int,int>m;
        set<vector<int>>res;
        bool flag=false;

        if(nums.size()<=2)
            return result;
        vector<int>temp;

        for(int i=0;i<nums.size()-1;i++)
        {
            int comp=-(nums[i]+nums[i+1]);
            if(m.find(comp)!=m.end())
            {
                auto location=m.find(comp);
                temp.push_back(comp);
                temp.push_back(nums[i]);
                temp.push_back(nums[i+1]);

                if(res.find(temp)==res.end())
                 {
                    res.insert(temp);
                    result.push_back(temp);
                 }

                temp.clear();
            }

            else
            {
                m[nums[i]]=i+1;
                m[nums[i+1]]=i+2;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

On giving input as 
[0,0,0,0]
Answer should be: 
[0,0,0]
Whereas I get :
[[0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

Comment: Where do you add anything to your `res` set?

Comment: Hi Shawn, 
My apologies, the code I had copied was incorrect. I have copied the correct code now. I by mistake pasted the code I was debugging on.

Comment: It is true that `std::set`s and `std::map`s contain unique values. Unfortunately this function is not returning a `std::set`, but a `std::vector`, which can contain duplicate values, and that's why you're getting them.

Comment: Hi @SamVarshavchik,
But I have created a set <vector<int>>. Hence shouldn't it also perform the function of giving us only unique results ?
If not, what is the alternative solution to this ?

Comment: Yes, you have created a `std::set`. And it will have unique values. But you're not returning this set. You're returning a vector. Just because you have a set doesn't mean that some other unrelated vector used in the same function will also have unique values. Can you point to the exact line in this function that makes sure that only a unique value gets added to the vector you're returning?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
````
if(res.find(temp)==res.end())
                 {
                    res.insert(temp);
                    result.push_back(temp);
                 }
````
If it is not a part of the set already, only then add the solution to the result vector, else it directly runs the clearing of temp vector part.

Comment: @Sma Why not create the set without any vector involved, then simply at the end of your function, copy the set's elements to a brand new vector and return that vector?  That would guarantee the logic working correctly.  I would also think that this method of doing things is more intuitive, unlike the way you're doing things now.  Given all that, you really should post a [mcve], because I hardly believe your issue has anything to do with the code you posted.  You are probably not getting correct answers due to other issues with your code.

Answer (score -1):

You could use tuples in the set instead of vectors.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using std::get;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::set<std::tuple<int,int,int>> sums;

    auto tup1 = std::make_tuple(0, 0, 0);
    sums.insert(tup1);
    auto tup2 = std::make_tuple(0,0,0);
    sums.insert(tup2);
    std::cout << sums.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto& item : sums) {
        std::cout << "(" << get<0>(item) << "," << get<1>(item) << "," << get<2>(item) << ")\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was downvoted?  The tuples in the set could easily be converted to the vectors that are returned by their 3sum function.